# import nested dict containing a list into a csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, import

I am trying to import the following data into a CSV:

```
{'test.foo.com': {'domain': 'foo.com','FQDN': 'test.foo.com', 'AS': 'AS1111', 'ressource_type': 'A', \
'nb_ip': '1', 'IP': '1.1.1.1', 'service': ['UNKNOWN'], 'port': '[443, 8443]'}}
```

I am nearly successful with this code:

```
#!/bin/python3

## Import ##
# Offical
import csv

### Main ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
  ## Variables
  csv_headers = ['domain', 'FQDN', 'AS', 'ressource_type', 'nb_ip', 'IP', 'service', 'port']
  final_data = {'test.foo.com': {'domain': 'foo.com','FQDN': 'test.foo.com', 'AS': 'AS1111', 'ressource_type': 'A', \
  'nb_ip': '1', 'IP': '1.1.1.1', 'service': ['UNKNOWN'], 'port': '[443, 8443]'}}

  # Open the csv file in "write mode"
  with open(file_name, mode='w') as file:
      # Prepare the writer to add a dict into the csv file
      csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=headers)

      # Write the columns header into the csv file
      csv_writer.writeheader()
      # Write the dict into the file
      for key, val in nest_dict.items():
          row = {'FQDN': key}
          row.update(val)
          csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

The result is:

```
domain,FQDN,AS,ressource_type,nb_ip,IP,service,port
foo.com,test.foo.com,AS1111,A,1,1.1.1.1,['UNKNOWN'],"[443, 8443]"
```

But I would like:

```
domain,FQDN,AS,ressource_type,nb_ip,IP,service,port
foo.com,test.foo.com,AS1111,A,1,1.1.1.1,'UNKNOWN','443'
foo.com,test.foo.com,AS1111,A,1,1.1.1.1,'UNKNOWN','8443'
```

See the difference ?
I have a list of "service" (no treatment needed here) and a list of "port".
If there is more than 1 port in "port" column I need to print a new row for each port in the list.

I am struggling to do that because I did not fully understand this code:

```
# Write the dict into the file
      for key, val in nest_dict.items():
          row = {'FQDN': key}
          row.update(val)
          csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Could you give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give the desired result with the given data:

```
### Main ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
  ## Variables
  csv_headers = ['domain', 'FQDN', 'AS', 'ressource_type', 'nb_ip', 'IP', 'service', 'port']
  final_data = {'test.foo.com': {'domain': 'foo.com','FQDN': 'test.foo.com', 'AS': 'AS1111', 'ressource_type': 'A', \
  'nb_ip': '1', 'IP': '1.1.1.1', 'service': ['UNKNOWN'], 'port': '[443, 8443]'}}

  # Open the csv file in "write mode"
  with open('out.csv', mode='w') as file:
      # Prepare the writer to add a dict into the csv file
      csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=csv_headers)

      # Write the columns header into the csv file
      csv_writer.writeheader()
      # Write the dict into the file
      for key, val in final_data.items():
          row = {'FQDN': key}
          # Assume that service is always a list of one value and replace it with the one value
          # it contains.
          val['service'] = val.pop('service')[0]
          row.update(val)
          # Since the value of port is quoted it will be a string, but we wat a list. Remove the
          # value of 'port' from the dict and put it in 'port_string' (= '[443, 8443'')
          port_string = val.pop('port')
          # Remove the opening and closing brackets from the port_string (= '443, 8443').
          port_string = port_string.replace('[', '')
          port_string = port_string.replace(']', '')
          # Now we can split the string into a python list (= ['443', ' 8443'])
          port_list = port_string.split(',')
          # Write a csv row for each value in the port list
          for port in port_list:
              row['port'] = port.strip()
              csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

(BTW, the code in the original post did not run.  This code includes edits to make it run.)

Note that since the value of 'port' is quoted (unlike the value of 'service') it will be read in as a string so it must first be converted to a list.  If the single quotes around [443, 8443] are removed then the port portion of the code simplifies to:

```
          port_list = val.pop('port')
          # Write a csv row for each value in the port list
          for port in port_list:
              row['port'] = port
              csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

The other potential issue is with 'service'.  It is a list so can it have more than one value?  If so, then the code will need to be modified to address that.

Finally, the code I present here can be more pythonic but wanted to make sure it is as readable as possible for starters.  It can be made more pythonic once it works completely as desired.

Comment: Daamn thank you for this detailed answer! You saved me quite a lot of research time.

I'll try it, understand it and then appropriate it for me.
I'll also try to remove the quote on 'port' so it can be treated as a list (it should return a list anyway).
Yes, 'service' could have several value and but I just need to transform it into a string (I don't need a row for each service).

Thanks again!

PS : Sorry if the code wasn't working I modified it a little (readibility and obfuscate some values)

Answer (score 0):

So this is the final code.

Not sure if it's the best way but it looks good enough for me.

```
#!/bin/python3

## Import ##
# Offical
import csv

### Main ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
  ## Variables
  csv_headers = ['domain', 'FQDN', 'AS', 'ressource_type', 'nb_ip', 'IP', 'service', 'port']
  final_data = {'test.foo.com': {'domain': 'foo.com','FQDN': 'test.foo.com', 'AS': 'AS1111', 'ressource_type': 'A', \
  'nb_ip': '1', 'IP': '1.1.1.1', 'service': ['UNKNOWN'], 'port': '[443, 8443]'}}

# Open the csv file in "write mode"
with open(file_name, mode='w') as file:
    # Prepare the writer to add a dict into the csv file
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=csv_headers)

    # Write the columns header into the csv file
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for key, val in final_data.items():
        # ?
        row = {'FQDN': key}
        # Update the row with all columns values
        row.update(val)
        # If service contains multiple elements it will transform the list into a string with each string separate by a space
        # If service contains just one element, it will transform the list into a string (no space) added
        row['service'] = ' '.join(val['service'])

        # Write a row for each value in the port list
        for port in val['port']:
            row['port'] = port
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Result Output:

```
domain,FQDN,AS,ressource_type,nb_ip,IP,service,port
foo.com,test.foo.com,AS1111,A,1,1.1.1.1,'UNKNOWN','443'
foo.com,test.foo.com,AS1111,A,1,1.1.1.1,'UNKNOWN','8443'
```

Don't up vote my answer, I put it for knowledge purpose.
All rewards should go to @bartonstanley